# Return a promise after .on event retrieves value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, tensorflow.js, ml5.js

I am using ml5.js PoseNet. I have a function that takes in an image and I'm trying to return the single pose generated by PoseNet. I also want to return this value as a promise. Using toReturn below, it returns before the pose is finished generating, so undefined (because of the asynchronous nature, I'm guessing).  How do I fix this?

```js
async function addPose(img){
    let options = {
        imageScaleFactor: 1,
        minConfidence: 0.1
    }

    let poseNet = ml5.poseNet(modelReady, options);

    function modelReady(){
        console.log('model loaded');
        let result = poseNet.singlePose(img);    // a promise of JSON value
        // return result;
    }

    let toReturn;

    poseNet.on('pose', function(results){
        toReturn = results[0]     // the JSON value
        // return results[0]
    })
    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ML5.js but you should use await to force it to wait for it to return before executing other stuff.

For example:

```
let result = await poseNet.singlePose(img);
```

To get this in a callable function after model has loaded you should reshuffle your code:

```
let modelLoaded = false;

async function loadModel() {

  let options = {
    imageScaleFactor: 1,
    minConfidence: 0.1
  }

  let poseNet = ml5.poseNet(modelReady, options);
}

loadeModel();


function modelReady(){
    console.log('model loaded');
    modelLoaded = true;

    // Feel free to register for events if you want:
    poseNet.on('pose', function(results){
      console.log(results[0]);
    });
}


function checkImage(img) {
  if (modelLoaded) {
    let result = poseNet.singlePose(img);
    return result;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: I see, but if I wrote return result after that, it would be returning result to the modelReady callback, instead of my addPose function. How do I make result the return value for addPose?

Comment: You need to split your functions out so  you can call a function as many times as you like. I will update my answer  1 moment

Comment: Updated answer. I made a check image function that only calls if posenet loaded already. else it will just return false, so you can call this as many times you like and will just start working once posenet is ready.  It seems posenet also has an on pose event handler too which means you may not need this dedicated function and instead you can just grab the results automatically from the pose event handler function you can register. Choose your preference.